# What is the explanation for these forms

Tags: word-usage

I was watching a movie on Netflix and suddenly, one of the characters said this to the other one:

```
FIND OUT WHERE HE'S WORKED,
WHERE HE'S GONE TO SCHOOL,
```

That blew my mind. He is worked???

Obviously, I understood what he meant, but this form is crazy, and the character is portraying a highly educated Harvard graduated person.

Comment: [This was asked before but closed as too basic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58921/does-hes-mean-both-he-is-and-he-has)

Comment: It isn't is worked. It's: **has worked**. Please review the contracted form of tenses. It is perfectly grammatical and not crazy at all.

Comment: thanks. I am losing my mind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"He's" is also an abbreviation for "He has".

Comment: I thought `He's` was `he is`... thanks

Comment: That is also correct.  He’s a carpenter. (He is a carpenter.)  He’s built several houses. (He has built several houses.) Never using contractions in everyday conversation can sound stilted, though.